# I need to two bookmarkets for delicious

Tags: delicious-api

I am current researching on something and I need to create , lets say, two bookmarkets. If I need to read this article later then I just want to click on that bookmarket and it should tag the current open page with read_it_later tag.

The second bookmarket should do similar thing. This one is for watch_video_later.

I don't want any prompt or anything.

I looked around but could not find any working delicious bookmarklet. You can assume that my userid on delicious is dorelal.

Thanks

I must use delicious because there are other people collaborating on this one.

Comment: Does stackoverflow need a "Belongs on getafreelancer.com" close reason?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using FireFox, get Read It Later add-on. It does all that and 100 other cool things.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://delicious.com/help/tools, there are bookmarklets and also links to applications / toolbars for various browsers